# Java JAX-WS Service with WCF Client

Tags: wcf, web-services, jax-ws, ws-security

Is it possible to create a WebService using JAX-WS, that whould then be consumed by a WCF client using such a binding?

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="CaseObjectServicePortBinding" >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

I created such a service without WSIT for now, just a plain service and wanted to just ignore the "Security" header in incoming SOAP message. But it fails with:

"Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'xxxxxxxxxx'."

If I change:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
```

to:

```
<security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
```

everything works flawlessly. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. You can use **BasicHttpBinding or WsHttpBinding**

The error was occurred because when you use **TransportWithMessageCredential**, the WCF client will impose additional security to your message sent through the wire, which is interoperable only to WCF service.

Once you changed it to **Transport**, only transport security( SSL using certificate) is applied , so that why both client and service can understand how to communicate with each other.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When defining security as `TransportWithMessageCredential` you say: *I want a service which will communicate over secured transport channel (HTTPS) and I want to pass client credentials in SOAP header.*

If you define Certificate credential type in message element you say: *The SOAP header will transport client credentials as x.509 Certificate token profile.* It is interoperable format which requires WS-Security on the service.

If you define Certifiate credential type in transport element you say: *I want mutual SSL authentication.* I'm actually not sure if this is used if you define `TransportWithMessageCredential`

Answer (score 0):

This happened on the step of initiating the request; the TLS exception pops out to you because the certificate set on the client is not trusted. Use a certificate with the common destination name, if you are using the service on public use the domain name else use the destination IP address as a common name and it will work just fine .

PS: Use the 'basichttps' binding in case you want to proceed with the https content type 'text/xml' soap 11 the the default from jaxws